# Changing states with <a href="/#/xyz> instead of <a ui-sref="primary"> using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJs V1.6. Ui- Router V 1.0.3

I've been trying to learn how to work with ui-router for the past few eeks and I came upon this code today which has me totally confused :-

Html side -

```
<ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="/#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS -

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
  })
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    resolve: {
      skipIfLoggedIn: skipIfLoggedIn
    }
  })
```

This is code from [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer).

I tried replicating it but all it did was end up showing me the folder structure of my working directory in the browser. 
However, I was using ui-router visualizer and upon clicking the route in that, it worked properly. I can't find any samples where ui-router is used this way, how exactly is this above snippet working?

I also read [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-simple-tips-for-using-ui-router) that typing

```
<a ui-sref="party">Go To Party</a>
```

will turn it into

```
<a href="/party" ui-sref="party">Go To Party</a>
```

in our browser. However, in the example I posted intially, there is no ui-sref with the href. Once again, how exactly or what exactly is happening? Is it only working because it's retrieving a separate html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use you are write this routing sample

```
<a href="/home">Home </a>
```

You must be write this code in the routing

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

[This link can help you](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372)

Answer (score 3):

> I tried replicating it but all it did was end up showing me the folder
>   structure of my working directory in the browser.

This happened because the first example in your question uses hash-prefix for generated links and the second example uses html5Mode for links.

When you click on a link with hash prefix mode eg. `#/home`, the request of that resource is handled at client-side by ui-router and is not sent to the server. But when you click on a link that is without prefix eg. `/home`, the request goes to the server. Your server needs to understand about this type of request (look at the referenced link below).

The default mode generates `#` as prefix. If you don't want to have hash prefix `#` in generated links then you need to enable HTML5Mode like this:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

If you enable this mode, then don't forget to inform Angular about the root URL of your app by adding following to the head section of your HTML file:

`<base href="/">`

Reference:

- [Read more about how to configure your server to work with html5Mode here.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

**About `ui-sref` directive:**

The preferred way of route/state resolution using ui-router in HTML templates is to use `ui-sref` which is a directive that binds a link i.e. anchor tag ( tag) to a state. If a state has an associated URL, the directive will automatically generate, update the `href` attribute for you.

This way your HTML template just needs to refer a state name and the link resolution will be done for you which is good as if in future you change the underlying link for states, your templates will still work. This directive uses `$state.href()` method for link value.

You can directly use the associated link in anchor tag without using this directive. But doing this, you will always need to revise your link if you change url in route config. Let ui-router module help you to manage this without writing any extra line of code and to ease state management.

The usage of this directive is:

- `ui-sref='stateName'` - Navigate to state, no params. 'stateName' can be any valid absolute or relative state, following the same syntax rules as `$state.go()`
- `ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})'` - Navigate to state, with params.

Example: If you html has following link:

```
<a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
```

The generated HTML (Html5Mode Off results in prepended '#') will be following provided your route config has a valid state named as `home`:

```
<a href="#/home" ui-sref="home">Home</a>
```

Reference: 
 - [UI Router ui-sref directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)

Comment: Resultant href depends on html5mode and hashPrefix settings also